# How to edit Active scene's GameObject from another script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am making a Unity project and I need to edit Text of some UI of current active scene from another different script (not linked to that active scene).

What I do is

```
            Scene scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
            Debug.Log (scene.name);
            if (scene.name == "RangeView") 
            {
                List<GameObject> activeObjects = new List<GameObject>();
                scene.GetRootGameObjects( activeObjects );
                for (int i = 0; i < activeObjects.Count; ++i)
                {
                    GameObject gameObject = activeObjects[ i ];
                    if (gameObject.name == "Clubdigit") {
                        gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = 10.ToString ();
                    } 
                    else if (gameObject.name == "Balldigit") {
                        gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = 10.ToString ();
                    } else if (gameObject.name == "Distancedigit") {
                        gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = 10.ToString ();
                    } else if (gameObject.name == "Ballspeeddigit") {
                        gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = 10.ToString ();
                    } else if (gameObject.name == "Distancedigit2") {
                        gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = 10.ToString ();
                    } else if (gameObject.name == "Backspindigit") {
                        gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = 10.ToString ();
                    } else if (gameObject.name == "Sidespindigit") {
                        gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = 10.ToString ();
                    }else if (gameObject.name == "Launchangleindigit") {
                        gameObject.GetComponent<Text> ().text = 10.ToString ();
                    }
                }

            }
```

The update is not reflected on the scene.
How can I update to the active scene?

Comment: I'm not quite following you... If the script isn't running, nothing's going to happen. Could you try to explain for what purpose you're doing this. Also, I'll do some refactoring that should help readability of your code meanwhile.

Comment: Thank you. I found the way. I need to search the child of the gameobject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you found the solution, great. It would be awesome if you would share the solution here in Stackoverflow, so that anyone else with similar issues can use your solution to help them. As a treat, here's some refactoring of your code to make it easier to manage and read, should you wish.

```
// Put the dependency Using System.Linq; at the top

List<String> objectsToChange = new List<String>() 
{
  "Balldigit",
  "Distancedigit",
  "Ballspeeddigit",
  "Distancedigit2",
  "Backspindigit",
  "Sidespindigit",
  "Launchangleindigit"
}

Scene scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
Debug.Log (scene.name);

if (scene.name == "RangeView") 
{
    List<GameObject> activeObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    scene.GetRootGameObjects( activeObjects );
    foreach (GameObject activeObject in activeObjects)
    {
        if (objectsToChange.Contains(activeObject.name)) 
        {
          activeObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = 10.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way, I need to search the child of the GameObject.

```
                List<GameObject> activeObjects = new List<GameObject>();
                scene.GetRootGameObjects( activeObjects );
                for (int i = 0; i < activeObjects.Count; ++i)
                {
                    GameObject gameObject = activeObjects[ i ];
                    Debug.Log (gameObject.name);
                    if (gameObject.name == "Canvas") {
                        foreach (Transform firstchild in gameObject.transform) {
                            Debug.Log ("firstchild name " + firstchild.name);
                            if (firstchild.name == "Swinginfo") {
                                foreach (Transform secondchild in firstchild.transform) {
                                    if (secondchild.name == "Clubdigit") {
                                        secondchild.GetComponent<Text> ().text = 10.ToString ();//result[0].ToString();
                                    } 
                                    else if (secondchild.name == "Balldigit") {
                                        secondchild.GetComponent<Text>().text = 10.ToString ();//result[0].ToString();
                                    } else if (secondchild.name == "Distancedigit") {
                                        secondchild.GetComponent<Text> ().text = 10.ToString ();//0.ToString ();
                                    } 
                                }

                            }else if(firstchild.name == "Swinginfo2"){
                                foreach (Transform secondchild in firstchild.transform) {
                                    if (secondchild.name == "Ballspeeddigit") {
                                        secondchild.GetComponent<Text> ().text = 10.ToString ();//result[0].ToString ();
                                    } else if (secondchild.name == "Distancedigit2") {
                                        secondchild.GetComponent<Text> ().text = 10.ToString ();//0.ToString ();
                                    } else if (secondchild.name == "Backspindigit") {
                                        secondchild.GetComponent<Text> ().text = 10.ToString ();//12.ToString ();
                                    } else if (secondchild.name == "Sidespindigit") {
                                        secondchild.GetComponent<Text> ().text = 10.ToString ();//13.ToString ();
                                    }else if (secondchild.name == "Launchangleindigit") {
                                        secondchild.GetComponent<Text> ().text = 10.ToString ();//result[3].ToString ();
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    } 

                }
```

EDIT:
According to the suggestion, my latest update is

```
            if (scene.name == "RangeView") 
            {
                List<String> objectsToChange = new List<String> () {
                    "Balldigit",
                    "Distancedigit",
                    "Ballspeeddigit",
                    "Distancedigit2",
                    "Backspindigit",
                    "Sidespindigit",
                    "Launchangleindigit"
                };
                List<GameObject> activeObjects = new List<GameObject>();
                scene.GetRootGameObjects( activeObjects );
                for (int i = 0; i < activeObjects.Count; ++i)
                {
                    GameObject gameObject = activeObjects[ i ];
                    Debug.Log (gameObject.name);
                    if (gameObject.name == "Canvas") 
                    {
                        foreach (Transform firstchild in gameObject.transform) {
                            Debug.Log ("firstchild name " + firstchild.name);
                            if (firstchild.name == "Swinginfo") {
                                foreach (Transform secondchild in firstchild.transform) {
                                    Debug.Log ("secondchild name " + secondchild.name);
                                    if (objectsToChange.Contains(secondchild.name)) 
                                    {
                                        secondchild.GetComponent<Text>().text = 10.ToString();
                                    }
                                }

                            }else if(firstchild.name == "Swinginfo2"){
                                foreach (Transform secondchild in firstchild.transform) {
                                    Debug.Log ("secondchild name " + secondchild.name);
                                    if (objectsToChange.Contains(secondchild.name)) 
                                    {
                                        secondchild.GetComponent<Text>().text = 10.ToString();
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    } 

                }

            }
```